# Always show error when connecting aws mysql via node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

I try to connect aws mysql via nodejs

```
var mysql      = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'xxxx.xxxc.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
  port      :  '3306',
  user     : 'dbusername',
  password : 'passwords',
  database : 'dbname'
})

connection.connect(function(err){

if(!err) {
    console.log("connected ... ")
} else {
    console.log(err)
}
});
```

When I run this code, and it will take some seconds, and then shows following error -

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:181:13)
at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)
errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
fatal: true }
```

I googled a lot, and couldn't find a right answer, and I try to use `node-mysql2`, has the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to ping the host `xxxx.xxxc.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com` from node server location?

Comment: Update: I find why, just change the sg, that's fine.

Comment: What is sg here?

Comment: @eduPeeth SecurityGroups

Answer (score 0):

Check it via connecting your mysql aws rds via any mysql client(mysql workbench, dbninja etc.), if you are able to connect it via any client then must be something wrong with the nodejs setup otherwise it will be issue with the RDS details.

Also check it if RDS has restricted access for particular VPN So your node server should be in same VPN to connect.

Answer (score 0):

By default, network access to AWS RDS instances is turned off.

I highly recommend to:

1. Test whether your instance with Nodejs is able to connect to the
   mysql instance. You can do by: 
   `sudo apt-get install mysql-client` (for Ubuntu)
2. Check security groups configuration of RDS instances. [Follow AWS
   tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html).
3. Follow [AWS RDS Security Best
   Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.Security)
   and configure the security groups appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things:

1-RDS security group and make sure your IP address can access to your RDS,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

2-Check your password